# Exist this vectorial equality, and this is correct?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

doing a problem about distance with vectors appears this identity:

$$\vec{A}\times\vec{B}=\frac{\vec{A}(\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B})-\vec{A}^{2}\vec{B}}{\lvert\vec{A}\lvert}=(\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B})\hat{A}-\lvert\vec{A}\lvert\vec{B}$$
I evaluate this identity in a formula that we know,and the result is ok.
The formula is this:

$$\lvert\vec{A}\times\vec{B}\lvert=\lvert\vec{A}\lvert\lvert\vec{B}\lvert\sin\theta$$
we know the norm of a vector is equal to the square root of dot product between them, then we have:
$$\lvert\vec{A}\times\vec{B}\lvert=\sqrt{\left[(\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B})\hat{A}-\lvert\vec{A}\lvert\vec{B}\right]\cdot\left[(\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B})\hat{A}-\lvert\vec{A}\lvert\vec{B}\right]}$$
$$=\sqrt{(\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B})^{2}-2(\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B})\lvert\vec{A}\lvert\vec{B}\cdot\hat{A}+\lvert\vec{A}\vert^{2}\lvert\vec{B}\vert^{2}}$$
$$\sqrt{-\lvert\vec{A}\vert^{2}\lvert\vec{B}\vert^{2}\cos^{2}\theta+\lvert\vec{A}\vert^{2}\lvert\vec{B}\vert^{2}}=\lvert\vec{A}\lvert\lvert\vec{B}\lvert\sqrt{1-\cos^{2}\theta}=\lvert\vec{A}\lvert\lvert\vec{B}\lvert\sin\theta$$
all look like the identity is right, Now my question is, this identity some one invent this before.
Thanks in advance friends.

Comment: you are saying a general statement, but your proof is only about the magnitude and do not account for direction.

Comment: @vaneet you right, the identity no works for direction, because the result vector live in the plane with create with the linear conbination of this two vector, and the cross product live out of that plane